# Merging data from two tables and adding a source column SQL/MSAccess

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I'm trying to merge several lists together in Access according to three particular columns (*First name*, *last name*, and *Postal Code*) and add a column to keep track of the data's source. I think I'm supposed to use some variant of a union query and an update query but it feels like I'm missing a piece.

I'm trying to do three things.

1. I'm wanting to make it so that if the text in all three of those columns matches, the query will recognize those two records as the same.
2. I'm wanting to make it so that if there are values in the records that do not match between the two sources that the record from one source will overwrite or be prioritized over the other unless the value is null.
3. I'm wanting to make it so that there is an additional column that lists the original table the record came from.

I've been able to merge the lists but its still producing duplicates. It's merging all the records without deleting or overwriting any records with conflicting data.

Here's a bit of a visualization:

Table 1 (Priority List)

```
FirstName|  LastName|   Pcode|                   Email
______________________________________________________
   Taylor|   Verrall|  V7W1B5| hello@taylorverrall.com
     Nick|     Smith|  V7G1F4|        nick@hotmail.com
```

Table 2

```
FirstName|  LastName|   Pcode|                   Email
______________________________________________________
   Taylor|   Verrall|  V7W1B5|     tbverrall@gmail.com
    Peter|     Jones|  V7Q3R2|    jones123@hotmail.com
```

What I am getting:

```
FirstName|  LastName|   Pcode|                   Email
______________________________________________________
   Taylor|   Verrall|  V7W1B5| hello@taylorverrall.com
     Nick|     Smith|  V7G1F4|        nick@hotmail.com
   Taylor|   Verrall|  V7W1B5|     tbverrall@gmail.com
    Peter|     Jones|  V7Q3R2|    jones123@hotmail.com
```

What I want:

```
FirstName|  LastName|   Pcode|                   Email|   Source
________________________________________________________________                   
   Taylor|   Verrall|  V7W1B5| hello@taylorverrall.com|  Table 1
     Nick|     Smith|  V7G1F4|        nick@hotmail.com|  Table 1
    Peter|     Jones|  V7Q3R2|    jones123@hotmail.com|  Table 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I know a very simple solution actually...I needed something like this days ago. You know you can select static values too :D like this...

Assuming you have the same number of columns on both tables do:

UPDATE(as per June7's feedback bellow :)

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *, "Table1" as tblName FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *, "Table2" as tblName FROM Table2
    WHERE NOT (FirstName, LastName, Pcode, Email) IN 
    (SELECT FirstName, LastName, Pcode, Email AS FLP FROM Table1)
) collection
```

This will produce a final result with all the data and at the end the name of the tables ;)

Comment: But this will return all 4 records. Requirement is to return only 3, no duplicate names.

Comment: @June7, sorry I had missed it. I will update now. I run the query you posted but it returned only first table's data with the "WHERE NOT..."

Comment: My SQL works for me - returns 3 records. Why are you including email in the filter criteria? User does not want 'all' the data.

Answer (score 0):

If Table1 has priority for selection of records, consider:

```
SELECT *, "T1" AS Source FROM Table1
UNION SELECT *, "T2" FROM TABLE2 WHERE NOT FirstName & LastName & Pcode IN (SELECT FirstName & LastName & Pcode AS FLP FROM Table1);
```

Maybe use just Pcode as criteria.

Comment: what is the purpose of the 'AS FLP' portion?

Comment: Just an alias fieldname. It might work without but I prefer to use. Try without if you want.